# Pagination and the rel next\prev

Tags: html

When I read google documentation on the rel="prev" and rel="next" all of their example are on the `<link>` element. When I look at stack overflow code, it's done on the `<a>` tag.

Does having a rel="prev" on a `<a>` good? I can't seem to find the documentation.
Or does it always have to be on the `<link>`.

Answer (score 2):

The `rel` attribute has the same meaning in both tags and can be used in each of them.

However unlike `a`, the `link` may only appear in the `HEAD` section of a document, although it may appear any number of times. 
Although `LINK` has no content, it conveys relationship information that may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways (e.g., a tool-bar with a drop-down menu of links). Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK)

At the `link`:

The **required** rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document/resource.

At the `a`:

The rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document.
Only used if the href attribute is present

Also according to W3C:
Links specified by `LINK` are not rendered with the document's contents, although user agents may render them in other ways (e.g., as navigation tools).
Even if they are not used for navigation, these links may be interpreted in interesting ways. For example, a user agent that prints a series of HTML documents as a single document may use this link information as the basis of forming a coherent linear document.